# Invalid characters in XML fails Datastage job

Tags: sql, xml, database, dataflow, datastage

I am a new developer who just started using datastage (coming from a bit of experience with SSIS). One of the first things that I am doing is working with XML data flow into a database from MQ. I connect to the MQ, use an XML job to map out the tags to each db column, and then insert it into the db. However, I am having an issue with the incoming xml. One of the fields on each xml file that I process contains the same character sequence which is something along the lines of "&$!0" .

When I run my job I get an error saying that that is an illegal xml character and the job fails.

Is there a way within datastage to replace this value as it comes through the xml, or even just remove it? Is there a specific tool I should be using within my job for this?

Obviously the easiest solution would be to fix that data coming in, however in the mean-time while that is getting squared away, I want to be able to do some testing, so an alternate solution would be great for now.

Any advice would be greatly appreciated. I am a new developer so I apologize if this question is a bit ignorant/low level.

Comment: Do you know what the data represents?  Removing it could cause problems if it's valid data that's just poorly represented in your XML.

Answer (score 1):

use a text editor like notepad++ to remove the characters yourself...

to automate, sed in linux will do your job and sed for windows will probably work on windows too!

Comment: It's actually not in the database load that it fails. It fails in the XML parsing portion. And I guess I was more or less wondering how to do get them out of there. Is there a specific tool within data stage designed to do that?

Answer (score 1):

These characters are nothing but Unicode. You need to remove them before you insert into DB table.

Try below code:

```
s = s.replaceAll("\\p{&$!0}+", "");
```

NOTE: You need to find out all Unicode and and replace them with "" (blank).

You will get more information [here](http://junidecode.sourceforge.net/)

Comment: Great! This helps a lot (also thank you for the link). However, the portion on which I am still confused about is this: My job in datastage consists of my mq connector, a data transformer, then a real-time "xml" job which inputs the file, and then I in the output step i map the database fields, and then it goes to an odbc connected database. The job fails due to the illegal value within the input step of the XML.

However, in the 2 days i've been using datastage so far, I haven't seen a place where I can input code (using 9.1) into the stream. Is this a specific tool in the palette?

Comment: As you are using ODBC driver I assumed you have SQL Server as database. Check http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/3119/import-utf8-unicode-special-characters-with-sql-server-integration-services/ and see if it helps